# pivot_longer to create more than one variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to use pivot_longer() to create two variables instead of one. My two variable names should be "stage" and "stock" with their corresponding values. The "stage" column should include rec, tadult and teggs. The "stock" column should have recStk, teggStk and tadultStk.

I have tried names_pattern below with a dummy example but I obviously don't know how to use patterns.

Could someone help with this? Thanks in advance

```
pivot_test <- structure(list(year = 1991:1996, rec = c(1635970, 1269210, 927557, 
1312280, 1387800, 1772490), teggStk = c(419648000, 411314000, 
445784000, 434684000, 364483000, 686490000), tadultStk = c(84009.2, 
58228.6, 65226.2, 44371.9, 65555.1, 79610.6), tadult = c(84009.2, 
58228.6, 65226.2, 44371.9, 65555.1, 79610.6), teggs = c(419648000, 
411314000, 445784000, 434684000, 364483000, 686490000), recStk = c(1635970, 
1269210, 927557, 1312280, 1387800, 1772490)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

  year     rec   teggStk tadultStk  tadult     teggs  recStk
1 1991 1635970 419648000   84009.2 84009.2 419648000 1635970
2 1992 1269210 411314000   58228.6 58228.6 411314000 1269210
3 1993  927557 445784000   65226.2 65226.2 445784000  927557
4 1994 1312280 434684000   44371.9 44371.9 434684000 1312280
5 1995 1387800 364483000   65555.1 65555.1 364483000 1387800
6 1996 1772490 686490000   79610.6 79610.6 686490000 1772490

annual21atest <- pivot_test %>% pivot_longer(-c("year"),
                                names_to=c("stage","stock"),
                                names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)",
                                values_to="quantity") %>% data.frame()
                                
  The final dataframe should have 4 columns:
  year stage   stock      quantity
  1991 rec     recStk     00000
  1992 tadult  tadultStk  00000
  1993 teggs   teggsStk   0000
  ...............................
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution. The problem gets a little funky because you've got the duplicated values for stage and stock which `pivot_longer` doesn't know how to automatically collapse. Instead, we drop the duplicated values to start with and then it's a single call:

```
pivot_test %>%
  select(year, ends_with("Stk")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "stock", values_to = "quantity") %>%
  mutate(stage=str_remove(stock, "Stk")) %>%
  select(year, stage, stock, quantity)
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 18 × 4
    year stage  stock       quantity
   <int> <chr>  <chr>          <dbl>
 1  1991 tegg   teggStk   419648000 
 2  1991 tadult tadultStk     84009.
 3  1991 rec    recStk      1635970 
 4  1992 tegg   teggStk   411314000 
 5  1992 tadult tadultStk     58229.
 6  1992 rec    recStk      1269210 
 7  1993 tegg   teggStk   445784000 
 8  1993 tadult tadultStk     65226.
 9  1993 rec    recStk       927557 
10  1994 tegg   teggStk   434684000 
11  1994 tadult tadultStk     44372.
12  1994 rec    recStk      1312280 
13  1995 tegg   teggStk   364483000 
14  1995 tadult tadultStk     65555.
15  1995 rec    recStk      1387800 
16  1996 tegg   teggStk   686490000 
17  1996 tadult tadultStk     79611.
18  1996 rec    recStk      1772490
```

Comment: Thank you all, will run it when I get home and select the best option

Answer (score 1):

The main challenge is to get the correct names pattern:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
  
pivot_test %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -year, 
                 names_to = c("stage", "stock"), 
                 names_pattern = "(.*)(Stk)", 
                 values_to = "quantity") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(stock = paste0(stage, stock))
```

```
    year stage  stock       quantity
   <int> <chr>  <chr>          <dbl>
 1  1991 tegg   teggStk   419648000 
 2  1991 tadult tadultStk     84009.
 3  1991 rec    recStk      1635970 
 4  1992 tegg   teggStk   411314000 
 5  1992 tadult tadultStk     58229.
 6  1992 rec    recStk      1269210 
 7  1993 tegg   teggStk   445784000 
 8  1993 tadult tadultStk     65226.
 9  1993 rec    recStk       927557 
10  1994 tegg   teggStk   434684000 
11  1994 tadult tadultStk     44372.
12  1994 rec    recStk      1312280 
13  1995 tegg   teggStk   364483000 
14  1995 tadult tadultStk     65555.
15  1995 rec    recStk      1387800 
16  1996 tegg   teggStk   686490000 
17  1996 tadult tadultStk     79611.
18  1996 rec    recStk      1772490
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pipe a call to `tidyr::pivot_longer()` for 'stock' into another call to `tidyr::pivot_longer()` for 'stage' or vice versa? It looks neat enough to me:

```
    pivot_test <- structure(list(
      year = 1991:1996,
      rec = c(1635970, 1269210, 927557, 1312280, 1387800, 1772490),
      teggStk = c(419648000, 411314000, 445784000, 434684000, 364483000, 686490000),
      tadultStk = c(84009.2, 58228.6, 65226.2, 44371.9, 65555.1, 79610.6),
      tadult = c(84009.2, 58228.6, 65226.2, 44371.9, 65555.1, 79610.6),
      teggs = c(419648000, 411314000, 445784000, 434684000, 364483000, 686490000),
      recStk = c(1635970, 1269210, 927557, 1312280, 1387800, 1772490)),
      row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 'data.frame')
    
    annual21atest <- 
      tidyr::pivot_longer(pivot_test,
                          -c('year', 'recStk', 'teggStk', 'tadultStk'),
                          names_to= 'stage',
                          values_to = 'quantity')|>
      tidyr::pivot_longer(-c('year', 'stage'),
                          names_to= 'stock',
                          values_to = 'quantity')|>
      as.data.frame()
```

The result is what you asked for:

```
       year  stage     stock    quantity
    1  1991    rec   teggStk 419648000.0
    2  1991    rec tadultStk     84009.2
    3  1991    rec    recStk   1635970.0
    4  1991    rec  quantity   1635970.0
    5  1991 tadult   teggStk 419648000.0
    6  1991 tadult tadultStk     84009.2
    7  1991 tadult    recStk   1635970.0
    8  1991 tadult  quantity     84009.2
    9  1991  teggs   teggStk 419648000.0
    10 1991  teggs tadultStk     84009.2
```

And you can also wrap the function like this for brevity:

```
    twostage.pivot_longer <- function(x, aggregated_names, aggregated_values,
                                      skipped_columns){
      # First aggregation
      y <- tidyr::pivot_longer(x,
                               -c(skipped_columns[[1]]),
                          names_to= aggregated_names[1],
                          values_to = aggregated_values)
      # Second aggregation
      y <- tidyr::pivot_longer(y,
                               -c(skipped_columns[[2]], aggregated_names[1]),
                               names_to= aggregated_names[2],
                               values_to = aggregated_values)
      return(y)
    }
```

and then use it like here:

```
    annual21atest_fun <- twostage.pivot_longer(x = pivot_test,
                                           aggregated_names = c('stage', 'stock'),
                                           aggregated_values = 'quantity',
                                           skipped_columns = list(
                                             c('year', 'recStk', 'teggStk', 'tadultStk'),
                                             'year'
                                             ))
```

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to produce the expected output - there's now a `quantity` variable that's appeared in the "stock" column, and every stage is linked to every stock? I agree that some more accurate expected output could help here but it seems like this is different than what was requested.